# Create action of changing value in custom slider

Tags: objective-c, swift, events, slider, action

I am using a framework called EFCircularSlider and successfully imported the objective-c files and now I am having trouble implementing this line of code in Swift:

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(newValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Here is my code for the circular slider so far.

```
@IBOutlet var currentValueLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let sliderFrame = CGRectMake(110, 150, 100, 100)
    let circularSlider = EFCircularSlider(frame: sliderFrame)
    self.view.addSubview(circularSlider)
}
```

I cannot get it to work the ways I tried to write it in Swift. I have tried writing it this way:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: "newValue:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Here is the way it is said to be implemented (https://github.com/eliotfowler/EFCircularSlider):
[image]

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error or `newValue(_:)` isn't called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Selector` in Swift, so like this:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: Selector("newValue:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Here is the whole `viewDidLoad()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let sliderFrame = CGRectMake(110, 150, 100, 100)
    let circularSlider = EFCircularSlider(frame: sliderFrame)
    circularSlider.addTarget(self, action: Selector("newValue:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(circularSlider)
}
```

Make sure that you implement your `newValue` method. Something like this

```
func newValue(slider: EFCircularSlider) {
    // Do you stuff here
}
```

Comment: It says "slider" is an unresolved identifier. Doesn't work when I change it to circularSlider Either (gets a crash).

Comment: Well in your case it's `circularSlider`

Comment: I added the whole `viewDidLoad` for your case

Comment: There was a crash. I think it might be the selector?

Comment: Probably, you have to implement that method (`newValue:`) in your code for the app to work.

Comment: I added the original instructions and link for initializing this. Of course I am trying to do it in Swift.

Comment: @D.Khan I added the implementation for `newValue` method that you need.

Comment: I'm not sure that is necessary according to the directions of the implementation I linked. I believe it is just the problem with that one line that I mentioned.

Comment: If you want to monitor changes. It is. You are adding a selector to be called in your code, but you're not implementing the function. That is why it crashes. If you don't need to monitor changes, then just remove `addTarget`

Comment: So to monitor these changes what do I write in the newValue function?

Comment: Yes. That method will be called each time user has moved the slider. If you wish to change something in real time, then implement it. If you just need a user to set something and tap a button to continue, then you do not need it. You can see that in their examples.